# Sphinx 4 terrible accuracy

Tags: java, sphinx4

I am trying to get sphinx 4 to work with my desktop application and it gets it right 0% of the time
also I'm using the default language models and all that stuff from the sphinx4 data.jar

code:

```
import edu.cmu.sphinx.api.Configuration;
import edu.cmu.sphinx.api.Microphone;
import edu.cmu.sphinx.api.SpeechResult;
import edu.cmu.sphinx.api.StreamSpeechRecognizer;
public class Speechy {
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    Configuration configuration = new Configuration();

    configuration.setAcousticModelPath("resource:/edu/cmu/sphinx/models/en-us/en-us");
    configuration.setDictionaryPath("resource:/edu/cmu/sphinx/models/en-us/cmudict-en-us.dict");
    configuration.setLanguageModelPath("resource:/edu/cmu/sphinx/models/en-us/en-us.lm.bin");
    Microphone micro = new Microphone(8000, 16, true, false);
    micro.startRecording();
    StreamSpeechRecognizer recognizer = new StreamSpeechRecognizer(configuration);
 // Start recognition process pruning previously cached data.
    recognizer.startRecognition(micro.getStream());
 while(true){
 SpeechResult result = recognizer.getResult();
 System.out.println(result.getHypothesis());
 }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> Microphone micro = new Microphone(8000, 16, true, false);
> ```

Default acoustic model requires 16khz audio, your configuration 8000 is wrong.

See also [the tutorial](https://cmusphinx.github.io/wiki/tutorialtuning/)

> The top reasons of the bad accuracy are:
>
> The mismatch of the sample rate/no. of channels of the incoming audio
>   or the mismatch of the incoming audio bandwidth. It must be 16kHz (or
>   8kHz, depending on the training data) 16bit Mono (= single channel)
>   Little-Endian file. You need to fix sample rate of the source with
>   resampling (only if its rate is higher than that of the training
>   data). You should not upsample a file and decode it with acoustic
>   models trained on higher sampling rate audio. Audio file format
>   (sampling rate, number of channels) can be verified using below
>   command sox --i /path/to/audio/file. Find more information here: What
>   is sample rate

Comment: I changed that after I posted the code and it still has bad accuracy

Comment: I fixed it by using custom language models and dictionaries

Comment: @thatmadhacker I am also facing same problem. How did you customize the language models and dictionaries?